# AttributeError in django-shopify-sync

Tags: python, django, shopify

I'm getting an AttributeError when running a command with the [django-shopify-sync](https://github.com/HandyCodeJob/django-shopify-sync) package for the first time:

After the initially setting up the package, I'm trying to run:

```
products = Product.objects.sync_all(query="Foo bar",session=sess)
```

The raised error is:

```
in sync_one
defaults.update({'session': shopify_resource.session.model})
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'model'
```

The error flows back to base.py. The applicable section of code in base.py:

```
# Synchronise instance.
    try:
        instance, created = self.update_or_create(id=shopify_resource.id,
                                                  defaults=defaults)
    except (utils.IntegrityError, Session.DoesNotExist):
        # This means that there needs to be the session in the defaults
        if isinstance(shopify_resource.session, ShopifySession):
            defaults.update({'session': shopify_resource.session.model})
        else:
            defaults.update({'session': shopify_resource.session})
        instance, created = self.update_or_create(
            id=shopify_resource.id,
            defaults=defaults,
        )
```

I'm not yet familiar enough with the shopify resource package to understand what may be the problem. I can't tell if it is something I may have set up wrong or it it is something poorly handled in the package itself.

Comment: My advice to you is to send Issue report to github page, maybe author will deal with it faster. Because i tried to look at the code, it's hard. And also, you won't get here much attention, cause it's not popular package. Best of luck!

Comment: Appreciate the advice. Thanks!